# How long does it take for PhD scholarship from DAAD

Tags: phd, application, funding, germany

One Germany university told me that they might offer me a PhD position.
But they have no funding for me. They are applying for DAAD scholarship.
They told me this a half month ago. However I asked them what is the current progress of my application few days ago. The professor has not replied me.
My question are:
       How long does it take for DAAD application?
       What is the success rate if the university help me to apply DAAD?
I don't know if my PhD application is still being considered?

Comment: If the grant application is specifically for funding your PhD work I would suggest to ask the DAAD.

Comment: Half a month means 14 days, which means they wrote to you New Years Eve. I do not think there is much activity then, and I assume there's a lot of activity now after the vacation, so a quick response would likely be overoptimistic. Whatever the case, in case the DAAD falls through, which always can happen, you should investigate additional opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I attended the “Research in Germany” events at the Fall Meeting 2015 of the American Geophysical Union in San Francisco. All of them were organised under the auspices of the German Research Foundation (DFG). You can have a look in the following webpage for more details: http://www.research-in-germany.org/en

Here is the link for research funding: http://www.research-in-germany.org/en/research-funding.html

Here is the link for financing and funding a PhD: http://www.research-in-germany.org/en/jobs-and-careers/info-for-phd-students/financing-funding-phd.html

Since you have already been selected in a PhD program, you can make application to many organizations for funding. Please have a look here: http://www.research-in-germany.org/en/jobs-and-careers/info-for-phd-students/financing-funding-phd/funding-for-phd-students.html